# Can you replace a REPLACE statement, or 9?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would really like something to replace all of these `REPLACE` Statements.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CAH.CaseNbr
    , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            (SELECT table1.Degree 
            FROM SDUJS.dbo.fnWorstDegreeCharge(CB.CaseID) AS table1), 'F1', 'F')
            ,'F2','F'),'F3','F'),'F4','F'),'F5','F'),'F6','F'),'FA','F'),'FB','F')
            ,'FC','F') AS Degree
    , dbo.fncasecounty(CB.CaseID) AS County
FROM
    Justice.dbo.CaseBase AS CB
    INNER JOIN Justice.dbo.xCaseBaseChrg AS xCBC WITH (NOLOCK) ON xCBC.CaseID = CB.CaseID
    INNER JOIN Justice.dbo.Chrg AS Chrg WITH (NOLOCK) ON Chrg.ChargeID = xCBC.ChargeID
    INNER JOIN Justice.dbo.CaseAssignHist AS CAH WITH (NOLOCK) ON CAH.CaseID = CB.CaseID
    INNER JOIN Justice.dbo.ClkCaseHdr AS CCH WITH (NOLOCK) ON CCH.CaseID = CB.CaseID
WHERE 
    CCH.DtFile BETWEEN '07/01/2010' AND '06/30/2011'
    AND 
    CCH.CaseUTypeID IN (858,4330,865,4329,6362,5112)
ORDER BY CaseNbr
```

All possible entries for that column

> M1, M2, MO, PO, CHINS, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, FA, FB, FC, 00

I want all the Felonies to be represented by `F`

---

## Code after the review

I decided not to do this as a follow up question because there isn't much that I think can be done to this query now to make it faster, except for get rid of the `DISTINCT` which I don't feel comfortable doing right now.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CAH.CaseNbr
    , (SELECT table1.Degree FROM SDUJS.dbo.fnWorstDegreeCharge(CB.CaseID) AS table1) AS Degree
    , dbo.fncasecounty(CB.CaseID) AS County
FROM
    Justice.dbo.CaseBase AS CB
    INNER JOIN Justice.dbo.CaseAssignHist AS CAH WITH (NOLOCK) ON CAH.CaseID = CB.CaseID
    INNER JOIN Justice.dbo.ClkCaseHdr AS CCH WITH (NOLOCK) ON CCH.CaseID = CB.CaseID
WHERE 
    CCH.DtFile BETWEEN '07/01/2010' AND '06/30/2011'
    AND 
    CCH.CaseUTypeID IN (858,4330,865,4329,6362,5112)
```

**Missing `REPLACE` statement**

I moved the "`REPLACE`" to the function that I am calling, but I used **@rolfl**'s wonderful Case Statement idea to get rid of all the `REPLACE` statements inside that function.

Comment: Are there, or can there be, other values starting with 'F' that would be broken if you selected the first leftmost character instead? It might be useful to include a few possible values of that field.

Comment: Warning: with nolock is dangerous: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5469238

Comment: @ChrisMathews, this is something that the Vendor told us to do, in order to speed things up. I am pulling data from a report server. if I put a lock on all these tables then I can't run concurrent reports, this can cause issues. that is the purpose of using `NOLOCK`  but thank you for that information.

Comment: @ChrisMathews, in other words there shouldn't be too much going on in terms of things being changed here, so the dangers are less than what you are thinking because of the way that the Databases are set up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This strikes me as best being done by using a temp table, or `with` clause.

Also, the DISTINCT part worries me.... why is that needed? Are your joins not good?

Still, I think you may have some more contentment with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CAH.CaseNbr,
    (SELECT CASE WHEN Degree in ('F1','F2','F3','F4','F5','F6','FA','FB','FC')
                 THEN 'F'
                 ELSE Degree
            END
     FROM SDUJS.dbo.fnWorstDegreeCharge(CB.CaseID)) AS Degree,
  dbo.fncasecounty(CB.CaseID) AS County
....
```

You should still consider a better mechanism for joining. The procedure route seems 'klunky'

Comment: it's a really bad Data Retrieval (PITA Report).  I am labeling a case with one Charge's degree, a case can have many charges and they can all be different degrees.  the data is good but what they want isn't always good for the data... does that even make sense?

Comment: the database tables are connected all over the place so I could end up with duplicated data.  I almost always throw it in there on this Database.  I probably don't need it on this query because it isn't bringing back more than a couple of columns

Comment: I like the `CASE` statement.  I will see if I need the `DISTINCT or not while at work today.

Comment: I will wait until the Question is Eligible for a bounty and then accept your answer.  I need the `DISTINCT` I am either not as good of a SQL Dev that I need to be, or the Database is really screwy....or both.  I can't believe that I didn't think of a Case Statement...Sigh.

Comment: That's why CodeReview is a Good Thing™ .... pulls on different people's eyes, experience, and opinions.

Comment: its for a report that has been stressing me out since I started.  finally got it whittled down to what the user actually needs and not "*what the legacy report returned*"

Comment: I ended up using the `CASE` statement inside the function instead of outside in this Query.  think I will post another Question, I have a lot of SQL to learn.